# Handle a char array returned from a function in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, memory

I am using a library called tinyXML, which parses XML files. Many of its methods return a const char*.

After having read this question:
[how to return a char array from a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443780/how-to-return-a-char-array-from-a-function-in-c)

I now believe that every time a method returns a char* it is the caller's (my) responsibility to explicitly free it, because it is *probably* allocated dynamically on the heap. Am I right / wrong? What can I assume?

(If I ever wrote a library I would much rather return std::string instead of char* arrays, because they are so much simpler for the user.)

Comment: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html: "TinyXML can be compiled to use or not use STL. When using STL, TinyXML uses the `std::string` class, and fully supports `std::istream`, `std::ostream`, `operator<<`, and `operator>>`. Many API methods have both `const char*` and `const std::string&` forms." Of course C doesn't have `std::string`, so an option to use `char*` is still necessary (assuming it can be used from C; I'm not sure of that). Also, the [home page](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml) suggests that "You may want to consider TinyXML-2".

Answer (score 7):

You can't assume anything and must check the documentation for the method you are calling to know if you must free the pointer or not. Sometimes a function returning a `const char *` might be returning a statically allocated string:

```
const char *getName(){
    return "SPQR3";
}
```

Or it might be a pointer that is someone else's responsibility to free. For example, `strcpy`'s return value is the same as the pointer you pass to it as input.

Answer (score 5):

Read the library's documentation. Both usages (pointer to an internal buffer, or pointer to a dynamically-allocated buffer) are common, and aren't distinguishable from the function prototype alone.